# Accessing Telegram Message by its id

Tags: telegram, telethon, messageid

I'm using Telethon Library to get messages, filter them, and a bit later if some conditions were met, reply to them with a specific answer.
The question is, can I get info about a message (most importantly its text), just by having its id?

Comment: Note that if all you want to do is reply, you don't need to get information about the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [client.get messages](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages) for that.

> If `ids` is present in the named arguments and is not a `list`, a **single Message** will be returned for convenience instead of a `list`.

Here is a minimal working example to get you the idea:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

API_ID= ...
API_HASH=" ... "

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

async def print_message():
    message = await client.get_messages('TelethonSnippets', ids=3)
    print("MESSAGE:", end="\n-------\n")
    print(message.text)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(print_message())
```